# Objects.filter(" ı wanna add two contains field")

Tags: python, django

This is search field. But in the views ı cant search on two field. I tried all of this. its not working.
its only working in one fields like = Makale.objects.filter(baslik__contains=keyword)

```
makale =  Makale.objects.filter(baslik__contains=keyword,icerik_contains=keyword)

makale = Makale.objects.filter(baslik_contains=keyword or icerik_contains=keyword)

def paylasimlar(request):
    keyword = request.GET.get("keyword")
    if keyword:
        paylasimlar = Makale.objects.filter(icerik__contains=keyword)
        return render(request, "feed.html", {"paylasimlar": paylasimlar})
    paylasimlar = Makale.objects.all()
    return render(request, "feed.html", {"paylasimlar":paylasimlar})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an *or* operator between two constraints by using [**`Q`-objects** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) and the [**or (`|`)** operator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#or), like:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Makale.objects.filter(Q(baslik__contains=keyword) | Q(icerik__contains=keyword))
```